Why this function caching gives me an error message for multiple dimensional np.arrays?
This is the code:
import numpy as np
from functools import cache, wraps


def np_cache(function):
    @cache
    def cached_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        args = [np.array(a) if isinstance(a, tuple) else a for a in args]
        kwargs = {
            k: np.array(v) if isinstance(v, tuple) else v for k, v in kwargs.items()
        }

        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [tuple(a) if isinstance(a, np.ndarray) else a for a in args]
        kwargs = {
            k: tuple(v) if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v for k, v in kwargs.items()
        }
        return cached_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.cache_info = cached_wrapper.cache_info
    wrapper.cache_clear = cached_wrapper.cache_clear

    return wrapper

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
y = np.array([2, 4])

@np_cache
def test2(x,shown = False):
  if shown:
    print(x)
  return x

#test2(y,True)
test2(x)

I get this error:
(array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]), True)
[(array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])), True]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-73b6dd94e3a9> in <cell line: 42>()
     40 
     41 #test2(y,True)
---> 42 test2(x, True)
     43 
     44 

<ipython-input-79-73b6dd94e3a9> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     23             k: tuple(v) if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v for k, v in kwargs.items()
     24         }
---> 25         return cached_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     26 
     27     wrapper.cache_info = cached_wrapper.cache_info

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

As you can see, The array is correctly converted to a tuple of arrays, so I don't know why it is not working.
I think the key is making some modifications in the wrapper, but I am not sure how.
Thanks in advance

numpy arrays are not hashable. when you use tuple on a 2 dimensional array, you get a tuple of 1 dimensional arrays, which is not hashable.

coming up with a good way to convert the array into a hashable object that you can round-trip is going to be complicated. do you have any constraints on the input?

It has to be an array, I think. Multiple input arguments are used for scipy.minimize() and it just receives numpy arrays for the evaluation of the objective function.

Numpy ndarray objects are not hashable, as you seem to be aware. But if you naively use tuple on a 2 dimensional or higher array, you get a tuple of ndarray objects, which is still not hashable.
So, if the arrays are going to stick to basic dtypes, you can use a quick and dirty function to convert to a nested tuple:
def _lol_to_tot_helper(lol, ndim):
    if ndim == 1:
        return tuple(lol)
    elif ndim == 2:
        return tuple(map(tuple, lol))
    else:
        return tuple(lol_to_tot(x, ndim-1) for x in lol)

def array_to_nested_tuple(arr):
    lol = arr.tolist()
    return _lol_to_tot_helper(lol, arr.ndim)

Although recursive, it shouldn't be terribly inefficient because one of the base-cases is the 2 dimensional case, so you won't recurse down into single elements. Be careful not to pass it something like np.array(1), i.e., a 0-dimensional ndarray.
